# Manga where the main character is betrayed and then reborn as the daughter of the ones who betrayed her

Tags: story-identification, manga, reincarnation

The main character gets betrayed and then is reborn as that villain's daughter. The first one she gets revenge on is the head maid. She pretends to be smitten with the maid. The head maid takes credit for the other maid's work. At one point, she mentions that she baked a cake personally for the lord, not knowing that the main character baked a rat into it.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Was this in full colour or mostly black & white? Also, what colour was the female lead's hair?

Comment: If anyone correctly identifies this, you can mark that answer as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Comment: Do you recall any romance in this story? "She pretends to be smitten with the maid" - romantically or just admiration? Do you recall if there are shoujo ai/yuri undertones (or explicit) references in the story? Do you have any idea when you read this?

Comment: it was admiration shes still a child at that point.  the maid wants to hang onto her so she can get benefits by being favored by the young lady

Comment: she takes revenge by using their greed and making them dig they own graves.

Comment: Do you remember what the MC was before reincarnating? Was she female? Male? A dragon? Was she a knight or some other combat-type, or a court noble?

Comment: maybe noble or princess but she was native to that world i dont think she was from japan

Comment: she was betrayed than born again as that betrayers daughter

Comment: female in both lives

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haha Kui Oujo no Kareinaru Hibi  [i found it but it was a novel not a manga]

https://anilist.co/manga/112242/Haha-Kui-Oujo-no-Kareinaru-Hibi

The Prince believed all of that woman’s lies and broke off his engagement with me. Even when I cried and begged for them to stop, that woman’s hired thugs came after me. As she saw all these tragedies happening to me that woman, my sister, sweetly smiled…

A year later, I was reborn as her daughter. Keeping both the memory and burning vendetta from my previous life, I had been given a second chance. I cast aside the weak person I was before in order to prepare for my counterattack. That was the only way I could crush all of my enemies.

…Now, it’s time to begin. I shall have my revenge on that woman.

Comment: i confused it for a manga so it was my bad. thank you qazlmpok for looking.